# Is it possible to provide an IP Address after flashing a new PC with Ubuntu image

Tags: configuration, static-ip

I was wondering is it possible to provide an IP Address after flashing a new PC with an Ubuntu image?
I'm flashing 3 raspberry pie for my K3S cluster and I was wondering if I can set a static IP address to my raspberry pie after I flash the SDCard from my laptop?

Comment: Great advice re: rewording the question.  Proper questions that show up on the main page and in searches are what can really make this forum magical.

Comment: @dennis I didn't get what you wrote, was it sarcasm?

Comment: @Oren it was not sarcasm. That was a response to a deleted comment. The deleted comment was incorporated into an answer below.

Comment: Ohhh, in that case, please excuse my rudeness @de

Comment: Glad that was made clear and correctly.  Absolutely no sarcasm, noticing you appeared relatively new to posting, I just meant to point out that great questions help everyone for years to come especially if you consider how heavily the site relies on search indexing.  Also that in the Stack communities often helpful suggestions go well beyond the actual answer Thanks @user535733

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are asking "*How do I set my Netplan config on this newly-flashed SD Card before I insert the card into a Pi and boot it for the first time.*" If I've misunderstood, then please edit your Question to clarify.

1. Use any File Manager to mount the SD Card and access the filesystem.
2. Look for the /etc/netplan directory. Your network config is stored in there.
3. Edit the .yaml file in that directory to assign your static IP address.

   See https://netplan.io/examples/ for how your .yaml file should look.
4. Unmount the SD Card. Insert the SD Card into your Pi. Boot the Pi.